# Unexpected token D

Tags: php, ajax, json

I understand this question has been asked many times but I am still not able to get the error. I am trying to parse text coming from server.

```
"MARUTI"
"MAHINDRA AND MAHINDRA"
"FIAT"
```

Every texts parsed except "MAHINDRA AND MAHINDRA". I do not understand where the problem is. here is my code.

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(httpxml.responseText);
```

Error in Console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token D
```

Please help.

Comment: The text you've provided is not JSON. Why are you parsing it as JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not a JSON String. You should inform about JSON

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Return a JSON string from your server. With PHP you can use `json_encode` to encode an array to a json string.

Comment: but what is the reason of the error even though I don't try to parse it.

Comment: Missed on mentioning I get the encoded string returned from my PHP code due to which I need to parse it. When a value is returned it is returned using the function json_encode($main)